# Ionic setRoot leaves multiple instances running at the same time

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I use `nav.push()` and `nav.pop()` for regular navigation, but when I don't want to allow the user to go back (like for example, setting the HomePage after a successful log in), I use `nav.setRoot()` with lazy loading. I am also calling `setRoot('HomePage')` to refresh the page when the users update their profile.

However, the problem that I'm experiencing is that the HomePage is getting loaded several times. Even when I press the refresh button in the browser, more instances show up in the console!

I have channelled all the setRoot calls through an event listener in app.component.ts to keep track of how many times it's being called, but everything looks normal. I've tried using `appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(page, args)`, but nothing changes.

Any idea where to look? Do I have to manually destroy the pages or clear the navigation stack after calling setRoot?

Thanks!

**EDIT (Some code):**

Subscription to setRoot event in app.component.ts:

```
this.events.subscribe('nav:setRoot', (data) => {
  let page = data['page'];
  let args = data['data'];
  if(args !== null && args  !== 'undefined'){
    this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(page, args);
  }else{
    this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(page);
  } 
});
```

From any page, when I want to set a new Root Page:

```
let arg = { page: 'HomePage'};
this.events.publish('nav:setRoot', arg);
```

Comment: `Few lines of code is worth a thousand words`.Can you share few lines of your code?

Comment: Hi Sampath, I've edited my question to show how I'm doing it. The navigation process doesn't really take that much code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
ionViewWillUnload() {
    this.events.unsubscribe("nav:setRoot")
}
```

this worked for me!

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made